# Unable to find class for driver smtp error sending emails in php

Tags: php, email

I checked out this similar question, but the answer wasn't useful: [Pear Mail "Unable to find class for driver smtp" Cannot find file, that is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337277/pear-mail-unable-to-find-class-for-driver-smtp-cannot-find-file-that-is-there)

So, basically I'm getting an error message of "Unable to find class for driver smtp". I am using Mail PEAR and Net_SMTP php files from:

https://pear.php.net/package/Mail/download

https://pear.php.net/package/PEAR/download

http://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP/download

and the section of code where I use these is here:

```php
require_once "Mail.php";
$from = "xyz@gmail.com";
$to = "xyz@gmail.com";
$subject = "Project Request: " . $_POST['project_title'];
$body = "Project In One Sentence: " . $_POST['project_in_one_sentence'] . "\r\n\r\n" .
    "Project In Detail: " . $_POST['project_in_detail'] . "\r\n\r\n" .
    "Client Name: " . $_POST['your_name'] . "\r\n\r\n" .
    "Client Email: " . $_POST['your_email'] . "\r\n\r\n";
$headers = array('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array('host' => 'smtp.gmail.com', 'port' => '465', 'auth' => true, 'username' => 'xyz@gmail.com', 'password' => 'xyz'));
if (PEAR::isError($smtp)) {
echo $smtp->getMessage() . "\n" . $smtp->getUserInfo() . "\n";
die();
}
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

I have all the files in the same directory. I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably not the answer wanted but if your not committed to pear, consider phpMailer, its the most used PHP mail libraries

Comment: eeek, just use [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), pecl/pear is such a hassle, and now we have composer makes them 80's package managers mute.